# udevadm and ATA Addressing

Tags: linux, udev, ata

In `udevadm info /dev/sda`, why are different ata values provided and which one is the preferred/more accurate address?

```
...
N: sda
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1.0
...
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:001f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda
...
E: ID_ATA=1
...
```

I see that the **by-path** is `...ata-1.0` but the **DEVPATH** has it as `.../ata3/...` and the **ID_ATA** is `1`

I would assume that the most accurate way to target a device is `/dev/disk/by-path/...` but I am not understanding the variations in the ata value.